# Is subscription product consumable in Android In-App Purchase?

Tags: android, in-app-billing

Is subscription product (product for which app user pay monthly or yearly) is consumable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No.  See [In-app Billing Version 3](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/api.html) documentation:

> Unlike in-app products, subscriptions cannot be consumed